# TYPO3, Fluid template. Display a div if the date of today is between 05/01 and 10/01

Tags: date, if-statement, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to display a div if the date of today is between "05/01" and "10/01". Could someone please help me with it? :)

I could only display it when the date is between "01/01" and "10/01" by writing this code:

```
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: '10/01' format: 'm/d')} < {f:format.date(date: 'now', format: 'm/d')}">
                <f:then><div>The Store is closed.</div></f:then>
                <f:else><div>The Store is open!</div></f:else>
</f:if>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine two conditions by "&&"

```
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: 'today', format: 'Y-m-d')} >=
{f:format.date(date: '2019/02/27', format: 'Y-m-d')} && {f:format.date(date:
'today', format: 'Y-m-d')} <= {f:format.date(date: '2019/03/01', format: 'Y-m-d')}">
  <f:then>
    <div>The Store is closed.</div>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
     <div>The Store is open!</div>
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Condition 1 (date of today equal or larger Feb 27):

```
{f:format.date(date: 'today', format: 'Y-m-d')} >= {f:format.date(date: '2019/02/27', format: 'Y-m-d')}
```

Condition 2 (date of today less or equal March 01):

```
{f:format.date(date:'today', format: 'Y-m-d')} <= {f:format.date(date: '2019/03/01', format: 'Y-m-d')}
```

Comment: TYPO3 error. Thank you for your respond. I just have tried it.It says: `#1244201848: A boolean expression has more than three parts.`

Comment: OK. You didn't mention the old version :-)
- You can nest your if conditions (dirty)
- Take a vhs viewhelper, which supports multiple comparisons
- or write your own viewhelper.
I would prefer writing an own viewhelper, based on the if viewhelper, with your own logic. The normal if viewhelper compares strings and not date formats, btw.